# Latch circuit with transistors which is initially on?

Tags: transistors, latch

I just learned about latch circuits and built the one displayed [here in Fig 75. Latch Circuit (B)](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/TheTransistorAmplifier/TheTransistorAmplifier-P2.html#Latch):

[image]

The LED is initially off. How can this be modified to be initially on?

Comment: The most reliable way is to add an inverter so the LED is off when the circuit is on, which consumes power in both states so it may not be ideal. Other methods are either complex or can be fooled by slowly increasing the supply from zero.

Comment: X-ray, this question is facing closure because it is asking us to design or modify an existing circuit for your needs. Perhaps rephrasing the question as "how does this circuit work" will help - plus, understanding how it works will help you make changes to it.

Comment: Why is it flagged as "unclear what you're asking" then? Isn't the question quite clear? I think I do understand how this circuit works (from reading other sources) - I just don't know how to modify it to my needs. I thought maybe for someone with experience it's just obvious.

Comment: Why is it not allowed to ask for a modification of a circuit to my needs? And if so, how would I have known that? I cannot find anything in the help section.

Answer (score 1):

The two transistor together form something like a SCR, and are either on or off.  There must be a wide enough hysteresis threshold between on and off so that the circuit keeps its state when both switches are open.

Since the initial state with no power applied is no current, it is easier for the circuit to start up with no current, meaning the off state.  It will be difficult to have the circuit reliably start in the on state, but otherwise have the condition of both switches open preserve the state.  Since the circuit powers up with both switches open, and must then turn on, how does it not turn on when both switches are open after power up?

There are some alternatives:

Use a capacitor to provide initial charge to turn on one of the transistors (which will turn on the other) when the power supply first comes up.  This will rely on some minimum dV/dt of the supply.  Put another way, this won't work if you bring up the supply slowly.

Use another transistor to invert the output of this circuit.

Use a different two-transistor bi-stable topology where one transistor is on and the other off.  Now you can connect the LED to whichever one you favor a little so that it powers up on.

Here is a example of such a bi-stable circuit:

[image]

Let's say Q2 is on and saturated, so has 200 mV C-E.  Assuming green LEDs that drop 2.1 V, that leaves 2.7 V across R1, which means the current thru it will be 5.7 mA.  The collector of Q2 is too low for Q1 to turn on, which would require about 2.1 V for the LED and abou 700 mV for the B-E drop.  Since Q1 is off, the base of Q2 is connected to 5V thru R2 and R3.  Again assuming 2.1 V LED and 700 mV B-E drop, the base of Q2 is at 2.8 V, leaving 2.2 V across R2+R3.  The Q2 base current is therefore (2.2 V)/(R2 + R3) = 210 µA.  That means Q2 must have a minimum gain of (5.7 mA)/(210 µA) = 27, which many small signal transistors can achieve at this voltage and current.

To allow forcing each of the two possible states, add momentary switches between the transistor bases and ground.

To have the circuit power up in a predictable state, add a little power supply bleed to one side.  But make sure this is not so much that the circuit flips back to that state after having been deliberately switched to the other state by momentarily shorting the base of a transistor to ground.

Comment: I tried (1.) with a 6.8 nF capacitor (smallest I have here right now) in different places (bridging S1, connecting Q2's collector to ground), but it doesn't work reliable when subsequently powering the circuit. About (3.) - which topologies would that be?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer and the detailed explanation of the flip-flop! How would this "add a little power supply bleed to one side" look like?

Comment: @x-ray: You've got to do a little thinking for yourself.  Give it some thought.  You should be able to figure something out.  Experiment and ask another question if needed, but let's see some effort and attempt to solve it first.